# formatting any content without selector

Tags: html, selector

I have :

```
<h3 class="maintitle">Here Text</h3>
```

I can add

```
<p></p>

<h3 class="maintitle"><p>Here Text</p></h3>
```

And format

```
.maintitle p {padding:10px;}
```

whether it is possible to do this without adding additional selector?

```
<h3 class="maintitle">Here Text</h3>
```

and

```
.maintitle <?> {padding:10px;}
```

I do not want to move content .maintitle ,only want to change the content inside without adding selectors

Answer (score 1):

Do not sure if I understand what you want but if you simply do :

```
.maintitle {padding:10px;}
```

All elements with the attribute **class="maintitle"** will be affected by your CSS modifications : p, span, div, ...

OR :

> h3 { padding:10px; }

...if you just want to set all your h3 padding

Comment: why don't you just use `h3 : padding:10px;` ?

Comment: oh, this could be the solution: D

Comment: Try `h3{padding:10px;}` instead of `h3 : padding:10px;` ... It was the morning...